# Does anyone know the name of the bnha fanfic where they write stories in a villain’s perspective?

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, my-hero-academia

Basically from what I remember was it was posted on ao3 and Aizawa gives class 1-a an assignment to write stories as if they were villains instead of heroes, but alas I can’t recall what the name was.

Comment: What is "bnha"? It may be obvious to those well-versed in SF&F, but it's not obvious to everyone. It would be useful to spell it out to help educate others.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [A Study in Firsts](https://archiveofourown.org/works/16340741) by [Oceanbreeze7](https://archiveofourown.org/users/Oceanbreeze7/pseuds/Oceanbreeze7), the [18th chapter](https://archiveofourown.org/works/16340741/chapters/79932541).
This fic is a bit like an anthology, and this chapter was centered around the concept of a mandatory paper for hero students to assess themselves and state their strengths and weaknesses and a scenario for why they'd be a villain.

> “so uh, what is the assignment?”
>
> Midnight’s smile struggled for the smallest moment. She said cheerfully, “roleplaying! You see, when you’re a professional hero, you never know who you may run into or what circumstance they have. To better theorize about a villain or vigilante backstories and motivations, you have to think about yours.”
>
> “What?” Sero whispered to Kaminari, who understood around 5 of her words individually.
>
> “Listen up,” Bakugou barked, turning his neck to gaze with one eye demonically over his shoulder. Kaminari paled, Sero gulped in pure terror. Bakugou said every bit the terrifying classmate he was, “this shitty assignment is to pretend you’re a goddamn villain and figure out why.”
>
> “What?” Hagakure squeaked in open horror, “that’s- that’s mean!”
>
> “I agree, this doesn’t seem like a manly assignment,” Kirishima said nervously, “like, we aren’t going to be-.”
>
> “You know,” Midnight mused loudly, “when I did this assignment, I hated it. I couldn’t afford to fail, but it wasn’t nice. It turns out,” she said with a serious and cold click to each word, “in the world of human and quirk trafficking, there are maintenance staff. They water and feed the cattle before they go to auction.”
>
> The classroom stared at her, speechless. Her nostrils flared slightly, when she smiled it wasn’t pretty. “It wasn’t an area we had a huge level of understanding in, more underground hero work. But some hero out there recognized a quirk like mine could very much be what they were combatting, and found a disgusting maggot of a person and broke a trafficking ring because of me.”
>
> She looked across the room, all false coyness and flirtations drifting away harshly. She said sharply and brutally honest, “it was because of this very assignment, that multiple people survived.”
>
> “When I had to do this,” Present Mic said with a similar grimace, “I figured out certain frequencies can do horrible things to hearing. Sometimes, it doesn’t only wreck hearing but ruins your ability to balance or walk. Wouldn’t that be scary in a hostage situation?”

and

> “But…” Midoriya said quietly, “...this is a complete villain backstory.”
>
> “Thank you,” Todoroki said simply.
>
> Shinsou stretched on his bed, foot overhanging far enough to nearly poke Todoroki on the forehead. Yawning loudly, Shinsou poked his head over the edge of the bed and gave Midoriya an unimpressed look. Shinsou said sleepily, “why are you acting all surprised? We all have dramatic villain backstories.”
>
> “I- you- he finished his in a day!”
>
> “Four hours after it was assigned, actually,” Todoroki corrected casually. >“I have a lot of feelings.”
>
> Midoriya spluttered, waving the paper dramatically. “You wrote that your only passion in life would be to murder your dad!”
>
> “A lot of homicidal feelings,” Todoroki corrected, “but only towards him.”
>
> “How are you so relatable?” Shinsou said as he chewed on a hangnail, “I just said I’d try to topple the hero industry by inducing public sightings of corruption, and gaslight Endeavour into prison.”
>
> “That’s exactly what I said.”
>
> “No, you said murder.”
>
> Todoroki shrugged on the carpet and scratched the cat with one hand.